# Zoned thermostat in every bedroom

Tags: air-conditioning, thermostat

I am getting a new AC and coils new use old one died

This is for second floor where we have 4 bedrooms

Question

1. Is it possible to have thermostat in every bedroom
2. Is it allowed under code ?
3. What components are required to make it happen
4. My contractor is also researching as he hasn't done but I would also like to understand the process too

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you really want independent temperature control of each bedroom?

Comment: Yes we occupy two rooms and two are mostly vacant so I would rather not send any air to those unless it hits like 80 during summer them other two rooms one gets too cold so having capability to control wild be great

Comment: How much re-engineering of your house's HVAC system are you willing to spring for?

Comment: I would install dampers on the vents controlled by a thermostat

Comment: if possible to do zoned with $1500 then I might go for it

Answer (score 1):

This is easily achieved with a **mini-split unit** for each room - that is also usually the most energy-efficent approach.

There are split systems with a single outside unit feeding up to 4 separate inside units (perhaps more, but that's the most I've noticed) but they have worse efficiency numbers than the one-head, one outside unit systems.

And, of course, a window unit in each room also achieves the same end, but less efficiently and with a somewhat cruder look (and without heating, normally.)

While you can set up zones via dampers in ducts from a central unit, the central unit will be operating inefficiently most of the time since it has to be sized for the entire house load, but would often be cooling a much smaller load.

Answer (score 0):

A thermostat is only useful if it has exclusive control of a source of heat or cooling. For instance, a three floor house often has three heating zones, with one zone and corresponding thermostat for each floor.

Adding additional thermostats without each having something to control would be a waste of thermostats. So, what will each thermostat control? Ed Beal's suggestion of having per-room dampers on the (presumably central A/C) ducts is a good one, but you'd have to be sure the control system can handle it (e.g. turning on the central A/C when the first room starts asking for cooling).